# I'm new to C++ and I have few questions I'd like to ask

Tags: c++

Question is :

```
Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline: 100
Original number of gallons is: 100
100 gallons is the equivalent of 378.54 liters
Thanks for playing
```

**how to display "Original number of gallons is: 100"
and my "Thanks for playing" is combined with "press any key to continue" I dont know how to seperate them.**

```
#include <iostream>
 using namespace std;
int main()
{
float g;
float l;

cout << "Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline ";
cin >> g;

l = g*3.7854;
cout << g << " Gallon is the equivalent of " << l << "liters" << endl;

cout << "Thank you for playing";

system("pause");
return 0;

}
```

Comment: `cout << "Original number of gallons is " << g << endl;`? And the second thing is because you forgot an `endl`.

Comment: You mean.... `cout <<  "\"Original number of gallons is: 100\" and my "Thanks for playing" is combined with "press any key to continue" I dont know how to seperate them."`

Answer (score 4):

1. [Do not use "use namespace std;"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-in-c-considered-bad-practice), this is bad practice.
2. [Using system("pause") is also bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1107705/systempause-why-is-it-wrong).
3. Use

   ```
   std::cout << std::endl;
   ```

To output a newline, to separate different lines of text.

Comment: It should actually be `std::cout << '\n'` to prevent an unnecessary flush.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <conio.h>   // Added for _getch();
#include <iostream>

// removed "using namespace std;"

int main() {
    float g = 0;  // Added Initialization To The Variables
    float l = 0;

    // From Here On Out I Will Be Using The Scope Resolution Operator To Access the std namespace.
    std::cout << "Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline" << std::endl;
    std::cin  >> g;


    l = g*3.7854f; // Added an 'f' at the end since you declared floats and not doubles

    std::cout "Original number of gallon(s) is: " << g << std::endl;
    std::cout << g << "Gallon(s) is the equivalent of " << l << "liter(s)" << std::endl;

    std::cout << "Thank you for playing" << std::endl;

    // Changed System( "pause" ); To

    std::cout << "\nPress any key to quit!\n";
    _getch();   
    return 0;

} // main
```

Answer (score -2):

Try placing the variables outside the main.
Also, get rid of the `system("pause");` and at the end of every `cout`, before the semicolon, add `<< "\n";`
At the end, the code should look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

float g;
float l;

int main()
{
cout << "Please enter the number of gallons of gasoline ";
cin >> g;

cout << "Original number of gallons is: " << g << "\n";

l = g*3.7854;
cout << g << " gallon(s) is/are the equivalent of " << l << " liters\n";

cout << "Thank you for playing\n";
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Globals that are not constant or static are bad practice and so is `using namespace std;`